# need to fill date field from another table in apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to fill date field from another table in oracle apex..

1. suppose i have a table name PC_info which have Pc name, purchase date, delivery date.
2. now i am creating a form like pc, purchase date, employe name, delivery date. now i want to input only pc name and other filed automatically fill up from PC_Info table.

everything is perfectly filled up but date not ok. date filled look like 5#x2F;30&x2F;2019' as i want it 5/30/2019.

please help me.

Comment: How do you *fill it up*?

Answer (score 0):

Can you format the date as a string?